# remove the index.php from url

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm using the last version of `CodeIgniter`, and want to remove the `index.php` from my url, and this is how my `.htaccess` file looks like :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /ci/ 

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

My base folder's name is `ci`, and my application folder's name is : `application`, and in my `config` file, I have this :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I searched about other solutions, but none of them has worked.

These are some of theme I tried :

## Solution 1 :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

## Solution 2 :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ci/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

## Solution 3 :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

## Solution 4 :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|css|js|lib|img|bootstrap|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]
```

## Solution 5 :

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: 4th option worked fine for me. what the error says?

Comment: @bprayudha it says that The requested URL was not found on this server.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i hope if it will help you, here's my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /project_folder/root-folder


    ### Canonicalize codeigniter URLs

    # If your default controller is something other than
    # "welcome" you should probably change this
    RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php)?)/?$ / [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce www
    # If you have subdomains, you can add them to 
    # the list using the "|" (OR) regex operator
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|subdomain) [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project_folder/root-folder$1 [L,R=301]

    # Enforce NO www
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]

    ###

    # Removes access to the system folder by users.
    # Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    # previously this would not have been possible.
    # 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.c

    # Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

And my config is :

```
$config['base_url']  = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/project-folder/root-folder';
$config['index_page']   = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```